# React custom hook not picking up new value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm still trying to wrap my head around how React Hooks work. In Building this custom Hook, I noticed a peculiar behavior:

```
const useCustomHook = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('hello');

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', print, false);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', print, false);
  }, []);

  const print = () => console.log('print value: ', value); // shows updated value when called directly but original value when scrolling

  return [setValue, print];
};
```

The peculiar behavior is what `print` outputs to the console. When calling `print` directly, the value reflects the correct updated value. But when scrolling, `print` always outputs the original value to the console.

Example usage:

App.js

```
let counter = 0;

const App = () => {
  const [setValue, print] = useCustomHook();

  return (
    <div style={{ margin: '50px auto 10000px' }}>
      <button onClick={() => setValue(counter++)}>Increment</button>{' '}
      <button onClick={print}>Print</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Steps:

1. Click <kbd>Increment</kbd>
2. Click <kbd>Print</kbd> -> console: `print value: 0`
3. Scroll -> console: `print value: hello`

Notice is step 3, the value is still `hello`. How can I get the proper value to be printed when scrolling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the dependencies from `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', print, false);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', print, false);
  }); // remove the empty array
```

If you set it to `[]`, then it will be executed only once.
If you remove it, it will be executed on every update.

Ideally, you want to re-evaluate the code in `useEffect` only when `value` changes.
You could then add `print` to the array of dependencies.

```
const useCustomHook = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(-1);

  // useCallback will re-create the function only if 'value' changes
  const print = useCallback(() => {
      console.log('print value: ', value);
  }, [value]);

  // useEffect will be re-evaluated if 'print' changes
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', print, false);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', print, false);
  }, [print]);

  return [setValue, print];
};
```

Comment: @goto1 Could you explain more ? It works for me and it doesn't make sens for me to recreate the function if `value` hasn't changed

Comment: Never mind, didn't see the use of `useCallback` - my apologies.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you.

Comment: So what I learnt from this answer and putting a whole bunch of `console.log`s in useCustomHook is that every time `value` changes, useCustomHook is ran again. And unless the scroll is de-registered and registered again, it references the old `print` function which created a closure around the original `value` and that's why the original value was being printed when scrolling. By ensuring that `useEffect` gets executed when `print` and `value` updates, it will ensure that the correct `print` reference (with correct `value` closure) is used during scroll. Makes sense now!